# is there a frictionless way to save input with multiple lines in firebase?

Tags: firebase

I'd like a user to be able to type several paragraphs as a firebase input and have the newlines/returns/enter preserved for formatting purposes. Neither the firechat or the more basic chat app in the tutorial provide this functionality ...

I've tried many things:

getting the html of my contenteditable div, then converting divs and brs to \r\n newline characters

using a textarea input instead of a contenteditable div

displaying the output in divs instead of lis

Is it possible that firebase does not save any whitespace characters except for the single space? their tutorial chat application exhibit this behavior, not supporting newlines/carriage returns or tabs for example

One approach that I would have expected to work is taking the html of the contenteditable div, saving it to firebase, and then adding that

Comment: Did you try anything yet? If so, please provide the code that you tried (there's a handy "edit" link right under your question for this purpose), tell us what you expected it to do and what it did instead.

Comment: If you are outputting your data as HTML(?), then of course simple line breaks don’t have any effect, they are condensed to a single space character as per HTML rules. In that case, you’d need to either convert them to `<br>`, or format your HTML to honor whitespace as it was input (CSS `white-space` property).

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest checking out **[Firepad](http://www.firepad.io/#1).**

- Firepad is a drop-in "Open source collaborative code and text editing" experience for Firebase apps.
- It is definitely frictionless.
- It will allow you to create the rich text-editor experience you're looking for.

As the [documentation](http://www.firepad.io/docs/) describes, this is how you initialize Firepad:

```html
<div id="firepad"></div>
<script>
  var firepadRef = new Firebase('<FIREBASE URL>');
  var codeMirror = CodeMirror(document.getElementById('firepad'), { lineWrapping: true });
  var firepad = Firepad.fromCodeMirror(firepadRef, codeMirror,
      { richTextShortcuts: true, richTextToolbar: true, defaultText: 'Hello, World!' });
</script>
```