# firebase three-way binding and ng-bind-html

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I'm creating a simple admin interface where an authenticated user is able to edit parts of a site, using firebase three-way binding (I'm using angularfire).

To be as user friendly as possible i at least want to allow them to have line breaks. Therefore i use ng-bind-html, but the problem is that real time validation will throw tons of errors until the entered html is valid (which is understandable).

I was wondering if this approach is even considered OK, or should i think differently. For example only update the view value once the user has finished typing, or create a button that would insert line breaks? Or maybe a filter that would return /n as `<br>`?

What are your experiences, suggestions? I dont really need html, the most i need is just line breaks.

Comment: If you want control over when Firebase gets to see the new data, don't use `$bindTo` but instead call `$save` explicitly.

Comment: No, don't use $bindTo() when you want control over when the data gets saved. Also, wouldn't a `textarea` allow you to have line breaks without HTML? It sounds like you're setting yourself up for an XSS attack, given the experience level of this question and the complexity of handling HTML securely.

Comment: i went with $save, so that i could skip realtime angular validation (the errors i got were due to that). i'm also replacing enters with <br> via a filter, and i still have to implement some regexp to filter out unwanted characters (strip html). Three way binding in my case would have been an overkill

Comment: As a side note, I'd recommend checking out [Firepad](http://www.firepad.io/#1). It may be one way to think differently about the problem and help simplify the situation. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29001171/1526037).

Comment: thanks for all the suggestions, i would upvote your comments if i could. i went with my own directive and the html5 contenteditable attribute, and of course implementing a parser for ngmodel